# Pass data to Service from main.ts file in Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v9

I have a main.ts file in my Angular CLI application which contains the following export..
By the way, it's a microservice which gets CONTEXT from another microservice

```
export default {
    async mount({ rootElement, context }: Extension) {
        // Here I need to pass data to MyService

        platformBrowserDynamic()
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    },
};
```

I also have service

```
MyService {
  context: any;
}
```

I need to initialize it with the Context from main.ts file. I can't do it in any other place, only here because I get data from another extension only in main.ts file.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to pass it in providers

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
            .bootstrapModule(AppModule, {providers: [{provide: CONTEXT, useValue: context}]})
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

and then just inject it wia the same token

```
class MyAnything {
  constructor(@Inject(CONTEXT) private context: any)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrei,

And what is CONTEXT here? We need to declare it somehow

Comment: it is an ijection token https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken